# How to create a Xamarin Tooltip in code-behind

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, tooltip

I am testing using the following example.  https://github.com/CrossGeeks/TooltipSample

The sample works fine, it even works with Labels (sample uses buttons, images and boxviews).  The issue is in my main App I need to create the tooltips in code behind.

To test how to do it, in the very same solution (from that above example) I created a TestPage and made it my MainPage in App.xaml.cs.  The  XAML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="ToolTipSample.TestPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout
        x:Name="mainLayout"
        BackgroundColor="Yellow">
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Handle_Tapped"/>
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The code-behind looks like this:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

using ToolTipSample.Effects;

namespace ToolTipSample
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TestPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var actionLabel = new Label
            {
                Text = "Show Tooltip",
                WidthRequest = 150,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Wheat
            };

            // Add tooltip to action label
            TooltipEffect.SetPosition(actionLabel, TooltipPosition.Bottom);
            TooltipEffect.SetBackgroundColor(actionLabel, Color.Silver);
            TooltipEffect.SetTextColor(actionLabel, Color.Teal);
            TooltipEffect.SetText(actionLabel, "This is the tooltip");
            TooltipEffect.SetHasTooltip(actionLabel, true);

            actionLabel.Effects.Add(Effect.Resolve($"CrossGeeks.{nameof(TooltipEffect)}"));

            mainLayout.Children.Add(actionLabel);
        }

        void Handle_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (var c in mainLayout.Children)
            {
                if (TooltipEffect.GetHasTooltip(c))
                {
                    TooltipEffect.SetHasTooltip(c, false);
                    TooltipEffect.SetHasTooltip(c, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All other code unchanged.

When I tap the label, the tooltip appears as expected.  **But when I tap the background it does not disappear** (like those created in XAML in the sample).

One other thing.  If I tap twice it disappears.

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and code, you can delete the following line code to achieve your requirement.

```
actionLabel.Effects.Add(Effect.Resolve($"CrossGeeks.{nameof(TooltipEffect)}"));
```

You don't need to add effect for control when page load, because this effect will be added when you click this control by these code:

```
 static void OnHasTooltipChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var view = bindable as View;
        if (view == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        bool hasTooltip = (bool)newValue;
        if (hasTooltip)
        {
            view.Effects.Add(new ControlTooltipEffect());
        }
        else
        {
            var toRemove = view.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is ControlTooltipEffect);
            if (toRemove != null)
            {
                view.Effects.Remove(toRemove);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That fixed it!  You know when you try just about everything apart from the one thing?  Marked as answer.